# Call a function with feval in Python

Tags: python, function, matlab

I am trying to translate an implementation of a code of mine written in MATLAB to Python language (using a style similar to MATLAB).

How to merge the `feval` call with the specific function call that implements a certain function?

Below is a sketch of code (incorrect) but that should give an idea of the result and the MATLAB code I would like to replicate to this [repository](https://github.com/SSPerotti/MasterThesis_FFTCOS/blob/main/MasterThesis_FFTCOS/cap2%20-%20FFTCOS/FFTCOS/getCharacteristicFunction.m)

```py
import numpy as np


def get_chf(model, u, t, r, q, *args):

    if model is 'BS':
        if len(args) == 1:
            return eval(chf_bs)(u, t, r, q, sigma)
        else:
            print('Invalid number of input arguments')

    else:
        print('Method non found')


def function chf_bs(u, t, r, q, sigma):
    i = np.complex(0.0, 1.0)
    # Drift correction term
    mu = (r - q) - 0.5 * sigma * sigma
    # ChF for the Black Scholes model
    cf = lambda u: np.exp(i*u*mu*t - 0.5*sigma*sigma*u*u*t)
    return cf
```